# How come only one of these functions will work at a single time?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Even if I remove the if statements, only one of these following will work at one time. To get the former to work, I have to comment out the latter.

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['region'])){
echo "<script> showRecords('".$_POST['region']."','region','country') </script>";}
if(isset($_POST['country'])){
echo "<script> showRecords('".$_POST['country']."','country','provice') </script>";}
?>
```

The script is referring to this:

```
function showRecords(str,column,nextDiv)
{
if (str=="")
  {

  document.getElementById(nextDiv).innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    document.getElementById(nextDiv).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","get"+column+".php?"+column+"="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The script leads to a very simple set of pages where that list some values based on some $_GET information.

I just cannot understand why it is only allowing me to do one of these scripts at a time. I even tried cloning the function to showRecords2, and it will still only do showRecords or showRecords2.

Comment: Your XmlHttp request object is sending a GET request, not a POST

Comment: Sorry, the $_POST is referring to the values specific to the page. What I am trying to do is have the proper lists loaded for when the user submits, and if he wants to submit some information that is only slightly different, he will have to make as few changes as possible.

Comment: It's cool 8) Any other ideas? I am banging my head into the keyboard right about now haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()` with `var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()`. Notice the **var** keyword added. What happened is `xmlhttp` is becoming a global scope variable and it gets overwritten with new values/argument/parameters everytime you make a request e.g. calling `showRecords` twice while the first one is still doing stuff the second call overwrites it.

Remember to make all your variables in the function level to avoid overwrites unless they are actually gonna be used in the global scope. It's time consuming to debug this kind of issues especially when you don't know where to find stuff. Hope that helps!

Comment: Wooops, I had a typo "provice" for "province". IT WORKS PERFECTLY :)

Comment: That is some good advice, trust me, I am gonna do that from now on.